# Is there any way to find all open directories using linux command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

i want to list all open directories for my linux based device. Plase any one tell that how to list all open directories in linux other than lsof commands, becase my device not support lsof command

Comment: What is your device and what version of linux are you running?

Answer (score 1):

lsof on Linux gathers file information from /proc, where each process' file descriptors are visible in its `fd/` subdirectory. To see all of them at once:

```
ls -ln /proc/*/fd/*
```

Optionally you can filter through `| grep -- "-> /"` to exclude sockets and other non-file objects.